# How to center layout with 2 uneven width containers

Tags: css

Desired layout:
[image: diagram of desired layout]

So I have this layout which should be centered and should not exceed `1440px`, it is split in 2 parts, let's call them 'sider' and 'content'. sider is `max-width: 560px` and container is `max-width: 880px`, together `1440px`.

Makes sense right? Content can be infinitely long AND scrollbar ABSOLUTELY has to be on the side of the screen.

So the million dollar question is how do I center these guys?

Here is a replicated, simplified code of my layout: https://codepen.io/andrisladuzans/pen/yLOajrX

HTML:

```
<div class="content-body">
  <div class="sider-container">
    <div class="sider-content">
      sider
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div id="populate" class="content">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.content-body{
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 90vh;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:flex;
}

.sider-container{
  background-color: pink;
  width:40%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:scroll;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.content-container{
  background-color: #ddd;
  width:60%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.sider-content{
  background-color:magenta;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 560px;
}

.content{
  background-color: lime;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 880px;
}
```

JS helper:

```
const content = document.getElementById("populate")

const populate = () => {
  for(let i = 0; i<50; i++){
    const textElement = document.createElement("div");
    textElement.className = "textElement";
    textElement.innerText = 'some text';
    content.appendChild(textElement)
  }
}

populate();
```

The problem with my approach is that, on larger screens, you can clearly tell that one side is growing larger than the other and is not centered.

[image: my failing result]

edit:

just realised, stackoverflow, has exact same layout i'm looking for.

solution:

a bit hacky, but here's what i finally managed to come up with (not responsive) https://codepen.io/andrisladuzans/pen/MWyjxLY

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .content-body {
        background-color: skyblue;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .container {
        background-color: pink;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
      }
      .inner-wrapper {
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid green;
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
      }
      .sider-container {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: magenta;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 300px;
      }
      .sider-content {
        background-color: magenta;
      }
      .content-container {
        background-color: #ddd;
        border: 1px solid midnightblue;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
      }
      .content-spacer {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }
      .content {
        background-color: lime;
        flex: 1;
        margin-left: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content-body">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
          <div class="sider-container">
            <div id="spacer" class="sider-content"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-container">
            <div class="content-spacer"></div>
            <div id="populate" class="content"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      const content = document.getElementById("populate");
      const spacer = document.getElementById("spacer");
      const populate = (element, text) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
          const textElement = document.createElement("div");
          textElement.className = "textElement";
          textElement.innerText = text;
          element.appendChild(textElement);
        }
      };
      populate(spacer, "spacer");
      populate(content, "content");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tnx for edit @Daniel_Knights . I guess i went a bit too freeform. Also English not my native.

Comment: if you're still tinkering, I'd suggest just wrapping your content-body in another div that is full width. Then just center content-body within that and don't set a width on it. As for putting the scrollbar over to the right, not so sure about that...

Comment: Oh man - was just messing around with this and having the scrollbar on the right like that certainly changes things... I may follow-up with an answer - let me know if you're still trying...

Comment: @MrRobboto not at the moment, had to go to work..., but yea i will have to get back to this later. Huge thanks for trying to help me out here.

Comment: @MrRobboto if you're interested i managed to come up with a ...'solution'. heyy it works..kid of....eh, close enough  :)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with my approach is that, on larger screens, you can clearly tell that one side is growing larger than the other and is not centered.

Not in my experience. At least from what I can tell from your codepen, everything works like you'd expect. Here is an image that shows that when I expand the window way past 4K size the container is still perfectly centered. Perhaps there is something on your browser or local machine causing a strange issue. Have you tried viewing your code on a different browser/computer?
[image]

Comment: omg, im so sorry, after i posted this, i went back and kept tinkering in code pen. Sory, i reverted changes back. Also i just realised stackoverflow actually has exactly desired layout i need , what an inception.

Comment: @AndrisLaduzans just to note, SO has a fixed width sidebar though which makes the layout a bit easier - the right side content can just be `width: calc(100% - 147px)`. Having your sidebar at 40% width makes that a bit harder...